# Creating a new Store Instruction LLVM

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, compiler-optimization, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I am working with LLVM IR code. I want to create a new `store` instruction ( Eg: `store i32 %add, i32* %temp1, align 4`) and I need to insert it after a particular instruction, say after an `add` instruction. My intention is, the result of an addition operation (some pointer) is stored in `%add`, I need to keep a copy of the same in a *temperory variable* say `%temp1`.

For that, I created a variable named `temp1` first (`%temp1 = alloca i32, align 4`). Now I want to store the result of addition instruction (`%add = add nsw i32 %0, %1`) i.e., `%add` to `temp1`. Then the final *store instruction* will be something like this: `store i32 %add, i32* %temp1, align 4`. How to do this?

Any help with some examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For creating `%temp1 = alloca i32, align 4` instruction, I used the following statement:

```
AllocaInst* pa = new AllocaInst(llvm::Type::getInt32Ty(getGlobalContext()), 0, 4,"temp1");
```

For creating and inserting a new `store` instruction:

```
StoreInst *str = new StoreInst(i, pa); // i -> current instruction pointer which represents %add ( source of store instruction ), pa -> destination. i.e., temp1
BB->getInstList().insert(ib, str); // ib -> instruction address before which you want to insert this store instruction
```

Comment: You can just pass `ib` to the `StorInst` constructor as third parameter. All instruction constructors take the insertion point as last parameter: e.g. `StoreInst (Value *Val, Value *Ptr, Instruction *InsertBefore)` and `StoreInst (Value *Val, Value *Ptr, BasicBlock *InsertAtEnd)`

Answer (score 1):

A couple of notes:

1. You should be using IRBuilder for creating IR. It's much easier and there are tons of examples to work off of in both the Kaleidoscope tutorial and clang itself.
2. I'm not sure why you're creating an extra allocation. In general, unless you have an actual local variable to store to a Value is sufficient to hold the result. What are you storing to and why?
3. If you do need an extra alloca for a local variable then you should create it in the entry block of the function, otherwise you'll be creating a dynamic allocation in the middle of your function.